# How do I get my for loop to print starting at the number one instead of zero

Tags: c++

I need my my program to start printing at the number 1 instead of 0. I tried changing my for loop to one instead of zero but then it prints one less of however many flips had been requested. I am sure there is a simple answer to this but I cant figure out anything.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < diceRolls; i++)
            {
                cout << " Dice roll " << i << " is " << rollDice(diceSides) << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Thanks for playing!";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int rollDice(int sides)
{
    return rand() % sides + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 cout << " Dice roll " << i + 1 << " is " << rollDice(diceSides) << endl;
```

Comment: My bad. just did it.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the for loop to have a less than or equal to (<=) condition instead of a less than (<) condition :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= diceRolls; i++)
     {
          cout << " Dice roll " << i << " is " << rollDice(diceSides) << endl;
     }
```

That way, the loop will start at 1 and iterate at the number of dice rolls. Good luck.